# Laravel 5.7 + Spatie Permissions + JWT auth

Tags: php, laravel, jwt, laravel-permission

I'm setting up a REST API using Laravel 5.7. To validate authentication I [JWT-auth](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/laravel-installation/) and for permissions and roles I use [Spatie](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission).

My problem: when trying to link a role to a user I get the following error

```
Spatie \ Permission \ Exceptions \ RoleDoesNotExist
There is no role named admin.
```

The role do exist in the database:
[image]

This is how I'm trying to assign a role to the user:

```
$user = User::findOrFail(1);
$user->assignRole('admin');
```

As I'm new to Laravel I'm not sure if it's relevant, but setting the JWT I had to change the driver of the guard in the `config/auth.php` to `jwt`

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'jwt',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. I added the roles and then tried to add the role to a user.

Comment: Have you installed all the packages ?

Comment: @AkhtarMunir yes, all packages, all the steps

Comment: Spatie is the developer btw. The package is `laravel-permissions`

Comment: I only bring this up because Spatie is a rather popular company that does open source development, especially with various laravel packages

Comment: Did you manually add those roles to the database?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your app namespace. If you updated it from `App`, be sure to update it in `config/auth.php`.

On the other hand, if you didn't update the `App` namespace, try clearing your cache and re-seed the database tables.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

**Also** check the user model if you have `protected $guard_name = 'api';` in there.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've manually added the roles to the database. The roles are cached and it causes issues if you don't use the built in create methods.

```
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Role;
use Spatie\Permission\Models\Permission;

$role = Role::create(['name' => 'writer']);
$permission = Permission::create(['name' => 'edit articles']);
```

> [From the GitHub docs](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/)

You will need to manually clear the cache with `php artisan cache:clear`.

The better way to do this is either to use a seeder (for permanent roles) or [Tinker](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#introduction) to run the code to create roles and permissions, which will trigger the cache to be cleared.

Comment: I added via code, not directly in the DB. Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

Guard has been changed from the web to api but still try to find web from the database 
assign a role like this.

```
$roleToAssign = Role:: findByName('administrator', 'api');
$user->assignRole($roleToAssign);
```

[#Link](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-permission/issues/781)

Answer (score 0):

If none of other answers solved your problem

Check that you are using queue
if so
restart the queue